# How to initialize an array with 2 others in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have one-dimensional array which i need to initialize with two others one-dimensional arrays, so i could have one array with values of two arrays. The length of arrays is dynamic, so the solution must work without accurate length values.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Edit:

I have two arrays which values depending on user input and i want to make a single array with the values of those 2 arrays.

Example:

```
int[] a = {2, 3, 4, 5};
int[] b = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
```

I need an array with values 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10.

Comment: It's fairly unclear what you're asking. It would be easier to help you if you'd show what you've tried so far *as code* and what happened.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int[] a = { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] b = { 5, 6, 7 };

int[] sum = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length + b.length);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sum));
// [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0]

System.arraycopy(b, 0, sum, a.length, b.length);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sum));
// [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use arrays this should work

```
  T[] newArray = new T[arr1.length + arr2.length];

    for(int i = 0;i<arr1.length;i++){
        newArray[i] = arr1[i];
    }
    for(int i = arr1.length; i<arr1.length+arr2.length;i++){
        newArray[i] = arr2[i];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want an arrayList which is dynamic grows and shrinks that includes another 2 arrayLists to make a 2D array.

```
ArrayList<Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> y = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> 2dList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
2dList.add(x);
2dList.add(y);
```

Answer (score 0):

So here is my solution for your problem:

```
    int[] a = {2, 3, 4, 5};
    int[] b = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10};


    int i = a.length + b.length;

    int[] c = new int[i];

    int temp = 0;
    for (int a2 : a) {
        c[temp] = a2;
        temp ++;
    }

    for (int b2 : b) {
        c[temp] = b2;
        temp ++;
    }

    Arrays.sort(c);
```

This is working for me :)